# Write complex SQL query to join five more table under given condition?

Tags: sql, join, database-design

This is my table design:

[image]

I write query to alone DrugPackage table like this and it work fine and give me 16 records.

```
Select  
    packText, ifnPriceAup
from 
    med.DrugPackage 
where 
    latest = '1' and available = '1' and baseDrug = '5102';
```

But I need to take, relevent BaseDrug table->name and also, Drug table->name and also, TradName table -> neme too. I tried lot of time using table join but I didn't succeed.

I write like this query but out put look like incorrect.

```
Select 
    brandedDrug.tradeName, basebrandedDrug.name, basebrandedDrug.id, 
    baseDrug.name, packText, ifnPriceAup 
from 
    med.DrugPackage  
left join 
    med.BaseDrug as baseDrug on med.DrugPackage.baseDrug = baseDrug.id  
left join 
    med.BaseBrandedDrug as basebrandedDrug on med.DrugPackage.brandedDrug = basebrandedDrug.id
left join 
    med.BrandedDrug as brandedDrug on  med.DrugPackage.baseDrug = brandedDrug.id 
where 
    med.DrugPackage.latest = '1' 
    and available = '1' 
    and baseDrug = '5102';
```

Output:

[image]

last three columns records correct but, first two incorrect. and also, I want to print tradename instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

when you use join, join with same datatype and related columns

```
Select brandedDrug.tradeName ,basebrandedDrug.name,
basebrandedDrug.id, baseDrug.name , packText, ifnPriceAup 
from med.DrugPackage  
left join med.BaseDrug as baseDrug on med.DrugPackage.id = baseDrug.id  
left join med.BaseBrandedDrug as basebrandedDrug 
on med.DrugPackage.id = basebrandedDrug.id
left join med.BrandedDrug as brandedDrug 
on  med.DrugPackage.id = brandedDrug.nplid 
 where med.DrugPackage.latest = '1' 
and available ='1' and baseDrug ='5102';
```

Comment: in Brandeddrug check the id name and use it correctly. I have a confusion whether it NPLID or NPIID